# reading files recursively and storing them java

Tags: java, vector

```
    public Vector readFiles(File Mydir) {

        Vector<File> vec = new Vector<>(10,10);  // to store the needed files

        for (File f: Mydir.listFiles()){
            if (!f.isDirectory()){
                System.out.println("file found"+ f.getName());
                vec.addElement(f);

                // reads all the files in the directory recursively
            } else
                readFiles(f);
        }
       // System.out.println("size of vec = " + vec.size());
        return vec;
    }
```

Hi I'm trying to read all txt and pdf files in a Directory and store them in a vector . but my vector only adds 4 of them as an element ! 
I printed the files and they are all found but not added to the vec . thanks for your help

Comment: Because you define a new vector in each recursion you have to Add all elements from the return value of `readFiles(f);` to the vector of the calling method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call recursively your method, you don't provide the valued vector :

```
   readFiles(f);
```

It is overwritten at each call :

```
public Vector readFiles(File Mydir) {

    Vector<File> vec = new Vector<>(10,10);  // to store the needed files
```